# How can I tell what causes a helm chart deployment to fail?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, rancher

If a Helm deployment's status is `failed`, what can I do to determine what made it fail?

Comment: What are the things you have tried already to determine this?

Comment: @rock'nrolla the nature of this question is general, I'm wondering if there's a canonical first few steps to be taken in order to determine deployment failures.

Comment: I see the other answers are good debugging/troubleshooting info.  I've tried to give the easiest and most direct way to find the deployment error.

Comment: Thanks @70Mike!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`helm history <release_name>`

Shows the kubernetes errors for the attempted deployment of that release.

Comment: The description just says `Upgrade "<release_name>" failed: context deadline exceeded`. What's the next thing I should check?

Comment: @CameronHudson That's the Kubernetes equivalent of a timeout.  Could be networking or lack of CPU/memory resources in the cluster.  Also could be a dependency like storage that took too long to be available.  The next answer down - '--dry-run --debug' could help.  You could also get helm to generate the manifest ('helm template...') and try (in a test cluster and/or namespace) applying that manifest to see what happens.

Answer (score 10):

**Helm chart deployment can fail because of the below 3 reasons.**

1. Chart is incorrect
2. Deployment configurations are incorrect.
3. Problem in Scheduling the containers and service due to some issue(image pull issue, resource quota)

The following steps can be performed for debugging.

**Chart correctness check**

Check the correctness of the chart using helm lint in local

`helm lint PATH [flags]  Ref: https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_lint/`

**Deployment configuration correctness check**

Check the correctness of the proposed deployment configuration using the flag --dry-run --debug

`helm install <ChartName> --dry-run --debug`

**Kubernetes cluster Deployment issue check**

To check the issues such as whether container creation is failing due to image pull failure or the pods are not getting scheduled due to resource crunch perform the following diagnostic.

Please add the namespace flag in each of the commands if your deployment is getting deployed in a particular namespace ( append -n <yournamespace_name>).
Look out for the items which are relevant to your helm chart.

`kubectl get deployment`

`kubectl describe deployment  <deployment_id_found_in_previos_step>`

`kubectl get rs`

`kubectl describe rs <resource_set_id_found_in_previos_step>`

`kubectl get pods`

`kubectl describe pods <pod_id_found_in_previos_step>`

See the output of each of the above-mentioned commands.

Answer (score 3):

Append the below parameters to the helm install command to validate the syntax and the command

```
--dry-run --debug
```

if the command works, then go ahead and run skipping the above parameters.

Comment: Yes. Updated the response